# SQL partial query

Tags: sql, tkinter

I'm trying to get a partial query using the LIKE command

```python
    def search(self, song="", artist="", date_added="" , rating=""):
        self.cur.execute ((
          "SELECT * "
          "FROM song "
          "WHERE song LIKE %?% OR artist=? OR date_added=? OR rating=?"
        ),(song, artist, date_added, rating))
        rows=self.cur.fetchall()
        return (rows)
```

Running this gives me the following error

```python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "c:/Python/Rating music/frontend.py", line 40, in search_command
        for row in database.search(song_text.get(), artist_text.get(), add_text.get(), rating_text.get()):
      File "c:\Python\Rating music\backend.py", line 20, in search
        self.cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM song WHERE song LIKE %?% OR artist=? OR date_added=? OR rating=?",(song, artist, date_added, rating))
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Adding quotation marks after the Like statement like so.

```python
    def search(self, song="", artist="", date_added="" , rating=""):
        self.cur.execute ((
          "SELECT * "
          "FROM song "
          "WHERE song LIKE '%?%' OR artist=? OR date_added=? OR rating=?"
        ),(song, artist, date_added, rating))
        rows=self.cur.fetchall()
        return (rows)
```

gives me this error

```python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "c:/Python/Rating music/frontend.py", line 40, in search_command
        for row in database.search(song_text.get(), artist_text.get(), add_text.get(), rating_text.get()):
      File "c:\Python\Rating music\backend.py", line 20, in search
        self.cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM song WHERE song LIKE '%?%' OR artist=? OR date_added=? OR rating=?",(song, artist, date_added, rating))
    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 4 supplied.
```

How can I change my query to filter data with `LIKE` predicate?

Comment: `LIKE '%' || ? || '%'`. (Alternatively `LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')`.)

Comment: LIKE '%' || ? || '%' removed the error but didnt return any value. and the second one gave this error

Comment: Did you try to run your query directly in database? Which code from the question works in it as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIKE ?` as below:

```py
def search(self, song="", artist="", date_added="" , rating=""):
    self.cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM song WHERE song LIKE ? OR artist=? OR date_added=? OR rating=?", ('%{}%'.format(song), artist, date_added, rating))
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return (rows)
```